# TensorFlow session with two neural networks - TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, typeerror

I have seen similar problems described on stackoverflow, but anything I found fit/solve my problem.

I have some reinforcement learning task, when I want to use two neural networks to steers two degrees of freedom.

I have a code like this with two neural network:

```
def reset_graph(seed=42):
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    tf.set_random_seed(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)

reset_graph()

n_inputs = 10
n_hidden = 8
n_outputs = 3

learning_rate = 0.0025

initializer = tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer()
X1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_inputs],name='X1')
hidden = tf.layers.dense(X1, 10, activation=tf.nn.tanh,name = 'hidden1', kernel_initializer=initializer)
logits1 = tf.layers.dense(hidden, n_outputs,name='logit1')
outputs1 = tf.nn.softmax(logits1,name='out1')
action1 = tf.multinomial(logits1, num_samples=1,name='action1')

cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels= action1[0], logits=logits1,name='cross_e1')
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate,name='opt1')
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(cross_entropy)


gradients = [grad for grad, variable in grads_and_vars]
gradient_placeholders = []
grads_and_vars_feed = []
for grad, variable in grads_and_vars:
    gradient_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    gradient_placeholders.append(gradient_placeholder)
    grads_and_vars_feed.append((gradient_placeholder, variable))
training_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars_feed)

X2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_inputs],name='X2')
initializer2 = tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer()
hidden2 = tf.layers.dense(X2, 10, activation=tf.nn.tanh,name='hidden2', kernel_initializer=initializer2)
logits2 = tf.layers.dense(hidden2, 3,name='logit2')
outputs2 = tf.nn.softmax(logits2,name='out2')
action2 = tf.multinomial(logits2, num_samples=1,name='action2')

cross_entropy2 = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels= action2[0], logits=logits2,name='cross_e2')
optimizer2 = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.002,name = 'opt2')
grads_and_vars2 = optimizer2.compute_gradients(cross_entropy2)

gradients2 = [grad2 for grad2, variable2 in grads_and_vars2]
gradient_placeholders2 = []
grads_and_vars_feed2 = []
for grad2, variable2 in grads_and_vars2:
    gradient_placeholder2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    gradient_placeholders2.append(gradient_placeholder2)
    grads_and_vars_feed2.append((gradient_placeholder2, variable2))
training_op2 = optimizer2.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars_feed2)


init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

and when I run it by :

```
action_val,action_val2,gradients_val,gradients_val2 = sess.run([action,action2, gradients,gradients2], feed_dict={X1: obs.reshape(1, n_inputs),X2: obs.reshape(1, n_inputs)})
```

I have an error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-fb66a94fa4dc> in <module>
     50                 reward, done, obs = agent.step(rotor_speeds)
     51 
---> 52                 action_val,gradients_val,action_val2,gradients_val2 = sess.run([action, gradients,action2, gradients2], feed_dict={X1: obs.reshape(1, n_inputs),X2: obs.reshape(1, n_inputs)})

...

TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>
```

The problem is with **gradients2**. When I calculate other parts of graph it work fine. For example:

```
action_val,action_val2,gradients_val = sess.run(([action1,action2,gradients]),feed_dict={X1: obs.reshape(1, n_inputs),X2: obs.reshape(1, n_inputs)})
```

it works without problems.

Also, I wonder why on graph generated from above code, the hidden layer(*hidden1*) and logits (*logit1*) of first neural network are connected to second optimizer(*opt2*) , because I don't see this unwanted connections in the code. Maybe it is the reason of problem, but also I don't know how to change it.
[image]

Comment: Two things I've noticed: in your error output, the line with the error has "X" where the rest of your code has "X1"; and cross_entropy2 is given the name "cross_e1". Can you check to see if either of these are the problem?

Comment: Thank for notice, but problem is still the same( I have the same error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at `gradients2`, since it seems to cause the error:

```py
>>> gradients2
[None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 <tf.Tensor 'gradients_1/hidden2/MatMul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1:0' shape=(10, 10) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'gradients_1/hidden2/BiasAdd_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'gradients_1/logit2/MatMul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1:0' shape=(10, 3) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'gradients_1/logit2/BiasAdd_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32>]
```

The first 4 elements are `None`, which explains why `sess.run()` fails (you cannot evaluate `None`).

So why does `gradients2` contain `None` values? These values come from `grads_and_vars2` so let's look at it:

```py
>>> grads_and_vars2
[(None, <tf.Variable 'hidden1/kernel:0' shape=(10, 10) dtype=float32_ref>),
 (None, <tf.Variable 'hidden1/bias:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32_ref>),
 (None, <tf.Variable 'logit1/kernel:0' shape=(10, 3) dtype=float32_ref>),
 (None, <tf.Variable 'logit1/bias:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32_ref>),
 (<tf.Tensor 'gradients_1/hidden2/MatMul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1:0' shape=(10, 10) dtype=float32>,
  <tf.Variable 'hidden2/kernel:0' shape=(10, 10) dtype=float32_ref>),
 (<tf.Tensor 'gradients_1/hidden2/BiasAdd_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32>,
  <tf.Variable 'hidden2/bias:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32_ref>),
 (<tf.Tensor 'gradients_1/logit2/MatMul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1:0' shape=(10, 3) dtype=float32>,
  <tf.Variable 'logit2/kernel:0' shape=(10, 3) dtype=float32_ref>),
 (<tf.Tensor 'gradients_1/logit2/BiasAdd_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32>,
  <tf.Variable 'logit2/bias:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32_ref>)]
```

The `None` values correspond to the variables `hidden1/kernel`, `hidden1/bias`, `logit1/kernel` and `logit1/bias`. These are the parameters of the `hidden1` and `logit1` dense layers. What does this mean? Consider how `grads_and_vars2` was computed:

```py
grads_and_vars2 = optimizer2.compute_gradients(cross_entropy2)
```

So we are asking TensorFlow to compute the gradients of `cross_entropy2` with regards to **all the variables in the TensorFlow graph**. This includes variables which `cross_entropy2` does not depend on at all, such as the parameters of the `hidden1` and `logit1` dense layers. This is why there are some `None` values.

And since `sess.run()` does not allow you to evaluate `None` values, you get an error.

To get rid of this error, you can simply filter out the `None` values:

```py
gradients = [grad for grad, variable in grads_and_vars if grad is not None]
...
gradients2 = [grad2 for grad2, variable2 in grads_and_vars2 if grad2 is not None]
```

The error should disappear.

As a side-note: I encourage you to check out TensorFlow 2 (with tf.keras): it's much easier to use.

Comment: So, as I understand connection between second optimizer (opt2) and hidden layer and logits in first neural network is normal behavior of TensorFlow?

Comment: Yes, in TensorFlow 1, `tf.gradients(foo)` or `optimizer.compute_gradients(foo)` compute the gradients of `foo` with regards to *all* variables in the graph (`tf.global_variables()`). This was a design flaw in TF 1, which was fixed in TF 2. In TF2 things are much nicer. You build a model (using tf.keras), and it has ownership of its variables. When you call `model.compile(...)`, the appropriate graph gets created, with gradients computed based only on the model's variables. Much cleaner.